# How to find mime Type of Blob

Tags: java, mysql, mime-types

I have an existing blob column in DB which has documents uploaded into it.
While retrieving them in another part of the application (new requirement) I would need to find the mimetype of the document that was uploaded before making it available on the front - end.

How would i be able to find the mime type of the document stored in the columns.

Am using Java with Mysql for the application

Regards

Comment: can you show up the table column structure ?

Comment: @SundarG : the document gets uploaded to column - resultFile ->  "LongBlob" and there is no separate column for inserting mimetype